# How to add a UI kit (such as Get Shit Done) to an existing Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline

I'm fairly new to Rails (and web development in general) and I'm trying to add the [Get Shit Done UI Kit](http://www.creative-tim.com/get-shit-done) (GSD) to my existing Rails-Bootstrap app (with Bootstrap already installed using the `bootstrap-rails` gem).

These are the files that come with this particular kit:

```
x_get_shit_done
--assets
---css
-----demo.css
-----get-shit-done.css
-----gsdk-base.css
-----gsdk-checkbox-radio-switch.css
-----gsdk-sliders.css
---img
---js
-----custom.js
-----get-shit-done.js
-----gsdk-bootstrapswitch.js
-----gsdk-checkbox.js
-----gsdk-radio.js
-----jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js
--bootstrap3
--index.html
```

This is how the stylesheets are called in the example template:

```
<link href="bootstrap3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets/css/get-shit-done.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="assets/css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

But in my Rails apps, stylesheets/JS are called like so:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

I understand that there is some magic that Rails provides for adding stylesheets to projects this way, but I don't quite understand how that magic applies to adding new custom stylesheets.

And additionally, all CSS files in my app (following a tutorial) are Sass (`.css.scss`), all HTML files are embedded Ruby (`.html.erb`), and Bootstrap is already installed using the `bootstrap-rails` gem.

Do I need to somehow convert the CSS files with UI kit to Sass? There's no gem for GSD so it seems necessary to add all of the styles manually, which is what I think is throwing me off here.

Thanks for your patience with this nooby's question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Allen I'm part of Creative Tim, we made the [Get Shit Done UI Kit](http://www.creative-tim.com/get-shit-done) and I would like to tell you that we've got a collaboration with a Ruby on Rails professional and we created a [Get Shit Done UI Kit Rails Gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/gsdk)

Please check it, it is hosted on the official [rubygems.org](https://rubygems.org/)  and let us know if everything is working as expected.

Best,
Alex

Answer (score 3):

First of all read about Rails' [Asset Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization) and you find the answers for all your questions.

In your case, you need to put `css` files to `vendor/asssets/stylesheets` and `js` files to `vendor/assets/javascripts`. Then add them with `require` to `application.css` and `application.js`.

**application.css:**

```
*= require_directory get_shit_done # this is vendor/assets/stylesheets/get_shit_done
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
```

**application.js:**

```
//= require_directory get_shit_done
//= require_tree .
```

After this all `css` and `js` files will be loaded to `<head>` automatically.

Then, you check `index.html` and change your `application.html.erb` according to it: add `<meta>`'s, some basic `div`'s, such as `div.container` in Bootstrap and so on. You don't need to add `css` and `js` files to layout, cause you've already done it with Asset Pipeline.

But I strongly recommend you to read about Asset Pipeline, `.erb` format and some other rails basics. It's better to start from them, not from implementing css framework to the project.

Comment: Awesome, thank you Peter. I understand how to do this now. And I will study the Asset Pipeline as you suggested.